# promise and deffered not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to call a function after the asynchronous call but after the asynchronous call function the normal function doesnt fire, I am not sure whats stopping it please help me to figure it out.I am trying to learn the concept of deferred and promise,don't know what I am missing.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kavinhuh/3jo9jmjn/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        $("#loadingimg").show();
        var promise = ajaxcall_function();
        promise.then(somes1());



    });

});
function somes1(){
   alert("dd");
}
function ajaxcall_function(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
      $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){                          
                $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
                $("#loadingimg").hide();       
                 deferred.resolve();
            }           
        });    
     return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Your ` promise.then(somes1());` should be ` promise.then(somes1);` Also you have the deferred anti-pattern $.ajax already returns a promise - see stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a wrapper you may try like this:

```
function ajaxcall_function(form){
    var form_data = $(form).serialize();
    var form_url = $(form).attr("action");
    var form_method = $(form).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
      $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){                          
                $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
                $("#loadingimg").hide();       
                 deferred.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
            }           
        });
     // Make other things here    
     return deferred.promise();
}

 ajaxcall_function()
 .done(function(returnhtml){
     // do something here with returnhtml
     // note the 'this' - scope is different because of .apply(this, arguments)
 })
```

And here is the refactored fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8a3mwkfp/4/

But take into account that the wrapper must make sense otherwise you should use the `$.ajax` return result as the `promise`.

Comment: There is no reason to use `$.when()` here - it is just a wasted extra function call.  The OP can just use `ajaxcall_function().then(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this:

```
 promise.then(somes1);
```

Instead of:

```
 promise.then(somes1());
```

The way you were doing it was calling the function immediately and passing the return results to `.then()`.  That is clearly not what you want.  Instead, you want to pass just a function reference (just the function name without the parenthese) so that it can be called later.  When you add `()` to the end of the function name, that means to call it immediately.

You can also simplify your ajax function like this to use the promise that is already returned from `$.ajax()` rather than creating your own:

```
function ajaxcall_function(){
      return $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false
        }).then(function(returnhtml) {                          
              $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
              $("#loadingimg").hide();
              return returnhtml;
        });    

}

ajaxcall_function().then(function(data) {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: if I want to pass some parameters to somek() ,how to do it without parenthesis

Comment: @user1386579 - you use a stub function: `promise.then(function() {somes1(xxx)});`.